# a word for functionalism as decoration

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

a word for an element of a design, or an object, that appears overtly functional but is decorative. 
ie, 4x4 rugged styling that is not functional; plastic bull bars.
Lots of buckles or oversized, clasps, giant rivets, on 'rugged''utility' combat style clothing or backpacks.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses. And much as I love the word gewgaw and am going to try to fit it into my everyday speach from now on, I still feel there is a particualr name of an ornament added to a design, to make it appear functional. I feel I did know this word but have forgotten, perhaps slang/recent?

Comment: thanks yes it could be steam punk, kitsh, or purely cosmetic,,,, but I still feel there is a particular word for these appendages to our designs, that are pervasive across many different styles?

Answer (score 1):

**gewgaw**, as defined by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gewgaw)

> Showy; unreal; pretentious.

It has a nice 600 year history, too. 1678, Dryden, John, *All for Love*, Scene II,

> The rattle of a globe to play withal, This gewgaw world, and put him
>   cheaply off.

Another example:  1855, Alfred, Lord Tennyson, *Maud; A Monodrama*, X, stanza 1,

> Seeing his gewgaw castle shine, New as his title, built last year.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the phrase "purely cosmetic", as it reflects that the only function is to affect the appearance of something rather than its substance.

Answer (score 0):

**Kitsch**

> 1:  something that appeals to popular or lowbrow taste and is often of
>   poor quality
>   2:  a tacky or lowbrow quality or condition

"Kitsch." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 13 May 2016.

There is a strong air of, shall we say, unoriginality about kitsch.

Of course, if it was done a long time ago, we call it neoclassical.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the ***"steampunk"*** fashion/style? It is a low-tech homage inspired by the writing of Arthur Conan Doyle and H.G.Wells. *(Think: 19th century mad-scientist or inventor.)*