# Word for "ornate but not pragmatic"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective describing an object designed for a use, but designed to be ornate without much regard to how well it fulfills its practical use?

For instance, someone might say *"Fountain pens are X."* because they are designed with a purpose-- to write-- but may not be as pragmatic or in some cases operate as well as the ballpoint.

Comment: I think fountain pens are a really bad example here.

Comment: @Jim - I use fountain pens almost exclusively. I prefer them. But my example illustrates what I'm looking for.

Comment: Was the "illustrate" pun intentional?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - No. Puns don't tickle me.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325455/a-word-for-functionalism-as-decoration

Comment: Fountain pens are obsolescent. They were, for a short time, the apex of practicality. In this, they were superseded, but you can't say they were impractical. An item produced to satisfy a desire for status moreso than to function well is a *gewgaw*. Gewgaws aren't always ornate, though. Sometimes, they can be downright agricultural-looking. But *gewgaw* does convey "pragmatic impairment" in spades.

Comment: The term is *award-winning design*. ;-) Another: *form flees function*.

Comment: @Myridium - “i’m looking at your statement: *”designed to be ornate ***without much regard to how well it fulfills its practical use***”. In my experience Fountain pens are painstakingly designed and refined to provide the best writing experience possible. Their designs are not “ornate first, practicality second.” the filigree and barrel materials all come second to the nib design and the ink delivery systems.

Comment: What I read as your question was what is the word for when ornamentation is taken to a point where it impairs functionality. I can picture things like chairs decorated with jewels such that it hurts to sit on it. Or a book so heavily ornamented that it won’t open fully anymore.

Comment: @Jim - I'm quite surprised at how much people are jumping to support fountain pens here... this isn't supposed to be a discussion about pens. I said someone **might** say they're impractical **because** .... It was just an example. I know that most fountain pens are designed to be practical yada yada; like I said, I use them every day. You have the right idea of what I'm looking for-- when ornamentation is taken to a point where it impairs functionality.

Answer (score 0):

***[Ornamental](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ornamental)*** conveys the concept of:

​

> - ***beautiful rather than useful:***
>
>   - *The handles on each side of the box are purely ornamental (= they are for decoration only).*

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: The meaning of *ornamental* does not exclude practicality or usefulness. (I think your answer partly reflects that fact, otherwise why would the Cambridge Dictionary qualify the word with *purely*). But there is nothing in the OED to suggest "rather than useful". Indeed the first sense (1a) listed by the OED of *ornament* - now said to be obsolete - is *†a. An accessory or adjunct, primarily functional, but often also fancy or decorative; (in pl.) equipment, trappings, furniture, attire. Obs.*

Comment: @WS2 - I think that ornamental may fit the context OP refers to. Why would you take with you a beautiful fountain pen? If you really need to write you would use a more practical pen or, nowadays,  an IPad probably. It is just an ornament like a precious wrist watch or a piece of jewelry.

Comment: As @WS2 has said, the qualifier *purely* is used there for a reason... because *ornamental* by itself is not enough. I don't understand your comment here, as some people do carry and use fountain pens (myself included) on a daily basis. Ironically, despite the definition you list, *ornamental* does have connotations of pragmatic impairment (at least in my opinion), and it is these connotations I'm looking for.